# I want to make an array like ["test": [[0.1,0.2], [0.3,0.4]]] in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to make an array like `["test": [[0.1,0.2], [0.3,0.4]]]` in Swift.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
var testArray = [String: [[Float]]]()
testArray["test"] = []
testArray["test"]!.append([0.1])
testArray["test"]!.append([0.2])
testArray["test"]!.append([0.3])
testArray["test"]!.append([0.4])
print(testArray)
```

I didn't want to be like this, but the output was:

```
["test": [[0.1], [0.2], [0.3], [0.4]]]
```

How can I get the output I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var testArray = [String: [[Float]]]()
testArray["test"] = []
testArray["test"]!.append([0.1, 0.2])
testArray["test"]!.append([0.3,0.4])
print(testArray)
```

Comment: or simply `testArray["test"] = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]]`